# How to access command switches in Magit

Tags: magit

Most `magit` commands are invoked with a single key, which pops up a menu of
subcommands and switches.  For example, <kbd>P</kbd> shows `P` and `t` as subcommands and `-f` and `-u` as "switches."

Hitting the letters for the subcommands invokes them, but how does one invoke
the switches?  I have a repository with two remotes, and I wanted to push to
the other remote.  The `-u` switch looks like just the thing, but if I type <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>-u</kbd>, the `-u` turns red, but Magit does not prompt for the remote.

The manual says nothing about these switches for any of the commands as far as
I can tell.

Could someone explain how these switches are used in general.  I'm not just
concerned with this particular switch, but with the facility in general.

Comment: To push to a remote, add a prefix argument before hitting `P P`.

Comment: while pressing `?` key from inside Magit is helpful to show  the menu, some keys are still not there. E.g. Try `l h` for reflog. So, I agree with you that a more extensive menu/help is still in need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way you are enabling the switches is correct, as evidenced by the fact that they "turn red" when you hit <kbd>-</kbd> followed by a letter.

In your case, `-u` simply isn't the switch you want. From `man git-push`:

> `-u`, `--set-upstream`
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add 
>     upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less `git-pull`(1)
>     and other commands. For more information, see `branch.<name>.merge`
>     in `git-config`(1).

So when you push with the `-u` switch enabled, you'll see something like this in the `*magit-process*` buffer:

> `0 git --no-pager -c core.preloadindex=true push -v origin foo:refs/heads/foo -u`
>
> Pushing to `https://example.com/project.git`
>
> Counting objects: 15, done. [...].
>
> **Branch** `foo` **set up to track remote branch** `foo` **from origin.** [...]

This tells you that Magit did in fact consider the `-u` switch.

---

As @TuDo points out, to get Magit to prompt you for a remote to push to, you need to hit <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>P P</kbd>.

---

#### Switches and Args

In general, when dealing with the menus that Magit provides for different commands it is helpful to remember that switches are just that: *switches*. You can turn them on and off, and that's it. They don't require you to supply any additional information, so Magit won't prompt you for anything when you turn them on.

Args, on the other hand, do require additional information, so when you tell Magit that you want to run a command with a specific arg it will prompt you accordingly. Args also differ from switches in that they are enabled by hitting <kbd>=</kbd> followed by a letter.